# Instance member cannot be used

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3

I have this splash view and I'm having problems with use3dtouch because I'm having an error telling me that splashview has no instance member 'use3dtouch'. Here is the code.

Here is an image of the error

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygmYH.png)

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class VPSplashView : UIView {
var vp = VPSplashView()
private lazy var __once: () = {
        if VPSplashView.traitCollection.forceTouchCapability ==     UIForceTouchCapability.unavailable
        {
            let longPressRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(VPSplashView.longPressed(_:)))
            self.addGestureRecognizer(longPressRecognizer)
            VPSplashView.use3DTouch = false
        } else {
            VPSplashView.use3DTouch = true
        }

    }()

static func addSplashTo(_ view : UIView, menuDelegate: MenuDelegate) -> VPSplashView{
    let splashView = VPSplashView(view: view)
    splashView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    splashView.isExclusiveTouch = true

    if (view.isKind(of: UIScrollView.classForCoder())){
        (view as! UIScrollView).canCancelContentTouches = false
    }

    splashView.menu?.delegate = menuDelegate
    return splashView
}

// MARK: Initialization
var menu : VPSplashMenu?

fileprivate var use3DTouch : Bool = true

var onceToken: Int = 0

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

init(view: UIView){
    super.init(frame:view.bounds)
    view.addSubview(self)
    self.menu = VPSplashMenu.init(center: self.center)
}

func setDataSource(_ source: MenuDataSource!){
    self.menu?.dataSource = source
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
     super.layoutSubviews()
    self.superview?.bringSubview(toFront: self)

    if (self.superview != nil){
        self.setup()
    }
}

fileprivate func setup(){
    _ = self.__once;
}

// MARK: Long Press Handling
func longPressed(_ sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer)
{
    switch sender.state {
    case .began:
        let centerPoint  = sender.location(in: self)
        menu?.movedTo(centerPoint)
        menu?.showAt(self)
        menu?.squash()

    case .ended:
        menu?.cancelTap()
        menu?.removeFromSuperview()
    case .changed:
        let centerPoint = sender.location(in: self)
        menu?.handleTap((menu?.convert(centerPoint, from: self))!)
    default:
        menu?.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}

// MARK: Touch Handling
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if (use3DTouch == true){
        var centerPoint : CGPoint = CGPoint.zero
        for touch in touches {
            centerPoint = touch.location(in: self)
            menu?.movedTo(centerPoint)
            menu?.showAt(self)
        }
    }
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if (use3DTouch == true){
        for touch in touches {
            let centerPoint = touch.location(in: self)
            if (menu?.shown == false){
                menu?.movedTo(centerPoint)
                if (touch.force > minimalForceToSquash){
                    menu?.squash()
                }
            } else {
                menu?.handleTap((menu?.convert(centerPoint, from: self))!)
            }
        }
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if (use3DTouch == true){
        menu?.hide()
    }
}

override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if (use3DTouch){
        menu?.hide()
    }
}
 }
```

Comment: how should i do that

Comment: can you help me out

Comment: so should I do "var SplashV = VPSplashView(use3dTouch)

Comment: Where do you put that code? In the class definition of `VPSplashView`? Is it a subclass of `UIView`? Conforming to any protocols? What are `use3DTouch` and `longPressed`? You are hiding too much. Please show more of your code before asking more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your added code has clarified some important things to write an answer...

- `traitCollection` is an instance property which is declared in `UITraitEnvironment`, where `UIView` conforms to
- `use3DTouch` is an instance property which is declared in `VPSplashView` explicitly
- `longPressed(_:)` is an instance method which is declared in `VPSplashView` explicitly

The third is not critical in this case, but the first two are clearly related to the error message you have gotten: *Instance member cannot be used*.

When you access to instance members (in this case, instance properties), you need to prefix an instance reference before `.memberName`, not a class name.

In your case, `self` seems to be an appropriate instance:

```
private lazy var __once: () = {
    //###
    if self.traitCollection.forceTouchCapability ==     UIForceTouchCapability.unavailable
    {
        let longPressRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.longPressed(_:)))
        self.addGestureRecognizer(longPressRecognizer)
        //###
        self.use3DTouch = false
    } else {
        //###
        self.use3DTouch = true
    }
}()
```

---

But you are doing things in far more complex way than needed, so you may need some more fixes.

One critical thing is this line:

```
var vp = VPSplashView()
```

This may cause some runtime issue (even if you have solved some compile-time issue) and `vp` is not used. Better remove it.